# Mechanics of Horizontal Stretching and Shrinking

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know $y=2f(x)$ doubles the $y$ value in vertical shifting, and I know that $y=(1/2)f(x)$ halves the $y$ value. But, why does $y=f(2x)$ halve the $x$ value, and why does $y=f((1/2)x)$ double the $x$ value in horizontal shifting? I looked at the graphs, and I see the difference, but I want to know the math behind why it halves instead of doubling the $x$ value for $y=f(2x)$. Maybe this is a stupid question, but could someone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you write the equation symmetrically, then both horizontal and vertical transformations follow the same “inverse” rules. I.e., let $g(x,y):(x,y)\mapsto f(x)-y$. Clearly, the graph given implicitly by $g(x,y)=0$ is identical to the graph of $y=f(x)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you let
$$\
g(x) = 2f(x)
$$
then in words you understand that

> The value of $g$ at some $x$ is twice the value of $f$ there.

You stretch the height of the graph of $f$ to get the graph of $g$.

If you let
$$\
h(x) = f(2x)
$$
then in words

> The value of $h$ at $x$ is the value $f$ has at $2x$, twice as far
>   along on the $x$-axis.

So to get the graph of $h$ on, say, the interval $[0,1]$ you find the values of $f$ on $[0,2]$ and slide them halfway to the vertical axis. That shrinks the graph of $f$ horizontally.

The same kind of analysis explains why $g(x) = f(x)+2$ shifts the graph up (positive direction) while $h(x) = f(x+2)$ shifts the graph left (negative direction).

Comment: "The value of $h$ at $x$ is the value $f$ has at $2x$, twice as far along on the $x$-axis." I thought that after all my years of teaching mathematics, I would have explained it as best I could, but this is way better than anything I've ever some up with. +1 (and +100 in spirit).

Answer (score 2):

Not a stupid question at all. A common and very reasonable question, in fact. Consider:

$$y=2f(x).$$

As you wrote, the graph will be stretched vertically by a factor of $2$. Note how it is written. The $y$ value equaled something, and we doubled that thing - we literally multiplied it by $2$.

When we write:

$$y=f(2x),$$

we do not operate in quite the same way. Instead of having $x$ equal something and doubling that thing, we have instead *halved the value needed to obtain a specific $y$*. It may be worth reading through that sentence a few times.

You cannot always do this easily, but if you take a simple enough function, such as perhaps $f(x)=2x+5$ and/or $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-1}$, and solve it for $x$, so that $x$ is a function of $y$, then the roles will switch. $f(2y)$ will be a vertical shrink by $2$, instead of a stretch. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubts last year when I was completing my high school math and I pretty much ended up memorizing the results but well... haha.

So here's how it works, when $y = f(2x)$ all values of $x$ are doubled.

What this means is say for example if you were to plot a graph of the function $f(x) = x^2$ and you were to plot $y = f(x)$ on the graph then when $x = 6$ $y = f(6)$ from $f(x) = x^2$ $y = 36$ this I am sure you can figure out.

But when you plot the graph of $y = f(2x)$ when $x = 6$ $y = 144$ not 36 so if you think carefully about it you realize that instead of $x^2$ $(2x)^2$ took place, instead of $6^2$ $12^2$ took place at the point $x=6$.

So where did the 36 go????

How about we try with $x = 3$ $y = f(2x)$ so $y = f(2*3)$ so $y = f(6)$ and this is the same as our first scenario, so because half the value of $x$ is required to plot the same $y$ point when $y = f(2x)$ the entire curve squeezes horizontally to half it's size.

If you attempt to take simple examples like the ones above to explain $y = f((1/2)x)$ I am sure you will realize why the curve stretches horizontally to twice it's size.

Hope that's the answer of your question.