# Questions on Spivak's proof that making x close to a is the same as making $x - a$ close to 0.

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

1. On my first attempt, I started with the left side of the question, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$. I defined it as $L$. I was befuddled after 20 minutes.

On my second attempt, I defined the right side of the question, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x-a)$. Again, I got befuddled for another 20 mins.

I didn't commence with  $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L$ because it doesn't appear in the question. Isn't it more natural to start with what appears in the question, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ or $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x-a)$? How do I do this?

2. I know $|y|$ means absolute value of y, but what does $y$ represent here? $y$ doesn't appear in the question.
3. Spivak "let $g(x) = f(x - a)$". Then $g(y) = f(y - a)$. Not $f(y + a)$?

Spivak, *Calculus* 2008 4 edn.  [His website's errata](https://mathpop.com/) lists no errata for these pages. I haven't MathJax'ed this to avoid typos.

Comment: $|x|$ is the absolute value of $x$. I'm not surprised that Spivak assumes you know that. For shifting, this may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307507/mechanics-of-horizontal-stretching-and-shrinking/3307525#3307525

Comment: $|y|$ denotes the absolute value of $y$. Spivak mentions this in the earlier chapters.

Comment: @EthanBolker sorry. i knew that. i re-worded my question.

Comment: @Joe sorry. i knew that. i re-worded my question.

Answer (score 1):

### Let's go through the proof again, a bit more carefully.

Suppose ${\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L}$. We will show ${\lim_{x\to a}f(x-a)}$ also ${=L}$.

By definition of the first limit, ${\forall\ \epsilon>0\ \exists\ \delta>0\ |\ |x|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\epsilon}$.

Let ${y=x+a}$. Notice that ${|x|=|(x+a)-a|=|y-a|}$. So we overall now have, with our new variable $y$ defined, that equivalently ${\forall\ \epsilon>0\ \exists\ \delta>0\ |\ |y-a|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(y-a)-L|<\epsilon}$ (all we have done is write the first limit definition with $y$ instead of $x$ being used). This is equivalent to saying
$$
\lim_{y\to a}f(y-a)=L
$$
which is what we wanted to show.

---

More generally, if you have some function ${c(x)}$ continuous at ${x=a}$, you have that
$$
\lim_{x\to c(a)}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(c(x))
$$