# If we know the graph of $f(x)$ and of $g(x)$, is there a way to graph their composition $f(g(x))$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, function-and-relation-composition

My question is that if we know the graph of $f(x)$ and of $g(x)$,
s there a way to graph $f(g(x))$

Example: $\sin (\ln (x))$

> [image: Graph]

How do we reach this graph? How does this graph relate to its parent functions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The question of "what does $f(g(x))$ look like in general" is rather broad, although there are some facts you can use, like if both $f$ and $g$ are increasing at a point then so is $f(g(x)).$ Similar with decreasing.

Comment: There is no general answer to this question. The function $g$ manipulates the domain of $f$ in a way that can be hard to describe explicitly. You can begin to see some hints at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307507/mechanics-of-horizontal-stretching-and-shrinking/3307525#3307525

Comment: You could plot individual points with (a variation of) the web diagram. Given input value $x$, move vertically to $(x,f(x))$ on the graph of $f$, from there move horizontally to the line $y=x$, from there vertically to $(f(x),g(f(x)))$ on the graph of $g$, and from there horizontally to $(x,g(f(x)))$. Not useful for the big picture but ok for a few points.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $g(x)=x^{2}$, then for $x < 1$ the graph of $f(g(x))$ will be squished compared to $f(x)$. This is only an example.

Take a point on the $x$ axis and apply to its value $g(x)$. It will be moved somewhere.[image]

Now, drawing the graph of $f(g(x))$ is like constructing a $2$-dimensional graph with the $x$ axis replaced with the second axis from above. The value corresponding to that $2$ of the second axis should be $f(2)$.

This can of course be applied generally. However, if you take $g(x)=\sin x$ or consider in my example also negative values of $x$ you will see that in your new graph you will have multiple $x$ values corresponding to a single $y$ which is not allowed.