# Derivative with respect to a modified independent variable

Tags: derivatives, substitution

I was not sure how to word this question, but I'm wondering how to evaluate
$$\frac{dy}{d(ax)}$$

where $y=f(x)$ and $a$ is a constant.

I was thinking I could write $y=f(ax/a)$ and rename $u=ax$, so $y=f(u/a)$. Then
$$
\frac{dy}{d(ax)}=\frac{dy}{du}=\frac{1}{a}f'(u/a)=\frac{1}{a}f'(x)
$$

This suggests a simple "hack" by evaluating the differential $d(ax)=adx$, so

$$
\frac{dy}{d(ax)}=\frac{dy}{adx}=\frac{1}{a}f'(x)
$$

I have a few questions:

1. Is there a name for this type of problem, where the you're taking the derivative with respect to a scaled or different independent variable? Is it just a form of variable subsitution?
2. Under what conditions can you simply evaluate the differential in the "denominator" of the derivative?

**EDIT**

Writing this problem as a composition of functions.

Let $u(x)=ax$ and  $h(x)=x/a$. Then, we can write

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{d(ax)}&=(f\circ h)'(u)\\
&=f'(h(u))h'(u)\\
&=f'(x)\frac{1}{a}
\end{align*}

I thought that perhaps I could use $(f\circ h\circ u)$, but it just gives me the original function.

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{d(ax)}&\neq(f\circ (h \circ u))'(x)\\
&=f'(h(u(x))h'(u(x))u'(x)\\
&=f'(x)\frac{1}{a}a\\
&=f'(x)
\end{align*}

Comment: The right way to check informal "variable substitution" arguments like this one is to write and name the functions explicitly enough to see the compositions, then use the chain rule.

Comment: Could you take a look at my attempt using compositions? Is the first part using $(f\circ h)$'(u) the best way to write it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=f(x)$ and $h(x) = ax$ and $g = f \circ h$. Then
$$
g'(x) = f'(h(x))h'(x) = af'(ax).
$$

To see that geometrically, suppose (for example) that $a=2$. Then the graph of $g$ on the interval between $0$ and $1$ is just the graph of $f$ on the interval between $0$ and $2$, compressed horizontally into half its width. So it is twice as steep.

You can rewrite that as
$$
f'(ax) = \frac{1}{a}g'(x)
$$
if that is what you mean by "$dy/dax$".

See
[Mechanics of Horizontal Stretching and Shrinking](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307507/mechanics-of-horizontal-stretching-and-shrinking/3307525#3307525)